# how to bulkcopy Excel file from Azure Blob

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have made an mvc application which saves excel file on azure blob blob storage. now i want to read the content of this excel file.

earlier i saved this file on my c:/temp folder and code to bulk copy it is as follows :-

```
         string excelConnectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data      Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", path);

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

        connection.ConnectionString = excelConnectionString;

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);

        connection.Open();

        DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myString"].ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
            {
               //my logic
             }
          connection.Close();
```

since i want to implement this solution on Azure cloud.

now i am saving excel file to Azure blobstorage instead of c:/temp.
but i am not able to bulkcopy it.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is a driver that comes with installation of Microsoft Office. There is no Office installed on any Azure Machine. In order to read the Excel file I suggest you to use [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) or some of the wrappers around it, like [OpenExcel](https://openexcel.codeplex.com/) or [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). If you need to read Excel File formats earlier than 2007, there is no easy way to do this in the Cloud.

As for the rest:
Everything else (BulkInsert, etc.) will work.
Rule of thumb - in general, in Web programming, in any programming, never rely on fixed/hard-coded paths!

Save the file locally, then bulk copy it.

For Web scenario, for **any** environment (not just Azure) you have at least two options to chose local path to save the file from the blob:

- [System.IO.Path.GetTempFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns
>   the full path of that file.

- Server.[MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) - [Server is property of either Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.server(v=vs.118).aspx) or a [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.server(v=vs.110).aspx) (System.Web.UI.Page) and is an Instance of [HttpServerUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpServerUtility(v=vs.110).aspx) type.

I personally prefer the latter - `Server.MapPath` with usage as follows:

```
var localPath = Server.MapPath("~/tmp");
var fileName = "name_of_my_file.xlsx";
var fullPathToFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);
```

This will give a full path to writable file within my web application in a folder "tmp" which in my Web Application root. I can also, using configuration (web.config) block all external access to that folder, so that it will only be accessible by the backend (controller actions, code, etc).

Using the former (System.IO.Path.GetTempFilename) will give you a unique file within the System TEMP folder. I wouldn't use that in any system - TEMP folder is a folder that any process can read and write to.

And if you don't know how to download the file from the Blob, read the `How to: Download blobs` from [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/).

Comment: Hi astaykov, this is a simple POC i am working on. so i skipped all the good practices :).

Comment: so, either I don't understand your question, or you - my answer. What is not clear ?!

Comment: i guess this doesnot work on azure(Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0)  i can not save the file locally. it needed to be saved on azure blobstorage. and contents of same file (which is on blob) are going to be copied in to sql server using bulk upload.